# Use Laptop As VM / RDP

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, usb-hub

I have been working from home during this pandemic and I alternate between using my work laptop and my personal computer. My personal computer has a much better processor and as such I greatly prefer it, but unfortunately I need to use my work computer to connect to things like VPN and to store work files.

My laptop is connected through a USB-C hub and I have a usb switcher so I can easily switch my inputs, so most of my usability problem is resolved. However, thinking about the setup has led me to the following idea:

When using a VM, when the window is active you are lending your mouse/keyboard, display, ethernet, etc. to the virtual machine. Since USB-C can support all of these, is it possible to create software such that you could plug a device into your computer via USB-C and have your computer emulate a USB-C hub to the laptop, but capture the output to a screen on your main computer, and send your desktop inputs to the laptop while functioning like a VM window? I know this would require a specialized expansion card that could act as a USB-C Client/Peripheral controller.

Does anyone know of software similar to this?

Comment: What would be the practical difference between this & 'regular' RDP?

Comment: Hmm i mean just a much higher bandwidth for the displays, and a lack of necesarry software on the client end. Do you think RDP could handle lets say dual 1920x1080 displays on LAN? Maybe I have not explored this option enough?

Comment: I use 2560x1440 all day, every day over LAN, with no issues.

Comment: Hmm. I'm just not confident my employer would be cool with me turning on RDP. I have admin but also don't want to upset the IT department lol. I suppose I will give it an ask. Thanks for your input.